# Friction on parabola

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation, friction, work, potential-energy

A block is released from $x=2, y=4$ on a wire frame with equation $y=x^2$ find its velocity when it passes through origin.
The coefficient of friction between block and wire frame is $k$.

I tried to solve this using conservation of energy, $W_{friction}-\Delta PE= \frac{mv^2}{2}$

What I am struggling with is how can I find the work done by friction if the normal is continuously changing.
Edit - Even if we apply work energy theorem, we get a v as function of x on lhs and v as a function of dv on rhs. So we cannot integrate. I have edited this so that this question reopens.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301)

Comment: @Kyle I think this is far from a "homework" question. While the premise seems like yet another textbook problem with a mass on a slide, the parabolic shape ruins everything. Differentiating seems unfeasible, maybe momentum conservation laws can help (we know that all acceleration by gravity was countered by normal and tangential forces ($v_y$ at the bottom is zero), but the problem is far from trivial -- I've spent a few hours but didn't get further than a differential equation. It's a shame, that this got downvoted and closed by formal attributes without deeper consideration.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP the level of difficulty pass irrelevant. OP asked us how to solve a particular homework problem, which is explicitly off-topic.

Comment: @Kyle 1) I'm quite sure that it's possible to rewrite this question to be on-topic (if I edit in *my* thoughts and effort in solving this, could it considered for reopening?). 2) In and of itself homework-and-exercise type questions are not explicitly off-topic. 3) Certain textbook problems illuminate physical *concepts* very well; there is good reason to believe that this is the case here. 4) If point 3 is not true, at the very least a resounding "no, this cannot be solved analytically" would be nice.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP 1. If you think you can rewrite it w/o violating the HW policy, feel free to do it. 2. Questions asking 'how do I solve this' *are* explicitly off-topic (see the help center). 3. Sure certain problems can, I don't see the concept being asked here, I see a request for the solution to a problem. 4. I don't see why we need to dignify a blatantly off-topic question with an answer of any sort.

Comment: @Kyle Thanks, I'll see (time-permitting) if I can suggest a good edit.

Answer (score 1):

The length of the parabolic path is given by,

$L=\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}\space.  dx$

(In the problem, $f(x)=x^2$)

Now all you have to do is to find normal reaction as a function of $x$, which should not be hard. Now you will be able to find work done by friction, which gives you the green light to use energy conservation.

Comment: Normal reaction would be $mv^2/r+mgcos@$ in the term $mv^2/r$ $r$ is also changing, the second term I can write as f(x) by changing $cos@$ but what should I do with the first term

Comment: Yeah, this won't do. On the other hand, acceleration of the body along the surface of the parabola will be given as $a=g\sin{\theta}-kg\cos{\theta}$. Now we know how to substitute the trigonometric terms by the abscissa of the body. We also know the length. You could apply the equation $v^2=2aL$. This is better.

Comment: Close, but might be hard. You'd rather want to substitute the trig terms by arc length, but alternatively you might want to consider just the abscissa projection of the acceleration.

Comment: Wait, on the other hand the second term of your acceleration is wrong because centrifugal force isn't accounted for. Back to square one...

Comment: Well, I was only concerned with the tangential acceleration. Centripetal acceleration wont change the speed of the particle.

Comment: No, but it will influence the normal force and, hence, friction.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Its hard to find an easy way for this question.